# Bootstrap 3: how to create an inline form with selects and labels?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

My labels keep appearing above the selects.  I want them all on the same line.  Pls see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjgelinas77/9nL9x/

```
<div class="well well-sm">
  <form name="myForm" role="form" novalidate="novalidate" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>C-Band</label>
      <select id="cband" class="form-control">
        <option value="C15+">C15+</option>
        <option value="C12-14">C12-14</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>C-Band</label>
      <select ng-model="form.cband2" id="cband2" class="form-control">
        <option value="C15+">C15+</option>
        <option value="C12-14">C12-14</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21):

There's a CSS rule in bootstrap that sets the width of `.form-control` to 100% on small screen sizes.  So even when it's floated, it will take the whole width and therefore start on a new line.  Good news is you only need a couple lines of CSS to override it:

```
.form-control {
width:auto;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Hope this simplifies the problem for anyone still facing the issue!  http://jsfiddle.net/c3m77ah6/2/

Answer (score 10):

You have to wrap your `label` around the `select`. Like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>C-Band
      <select id="cband" class="form-control">
         <option value="C15+">C15+</option>
         <option value="C12-14">C12-14</option>
         <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
  </label> 
</div>
```

And then add the following CSS:

```
.form-group label {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.form-group select {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is your updated fiddle: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nL9x/30/)

Comment: Despite your code works, it looks like a hack and not a proper way to get label with select on one line.

Comment: While I don't feel it's especially semantic (an input and a label are more of a pair/sibling than parent/child in my opinion), this does validate for HTML 5, so I wouldn't consider it a hack.  However, it takes more CSS to do it this way than simply tweak the Bootstrap styles for the original markup.

Comment: to make it not so much a "hack" just add another class to your form-group and change the selector from .form-group to .form-group.yourselector so you aren't changing every form-group on the page.

Answer (score 5):

form-inline class with form-group will do the job like

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
<label for="sel1">My InlineSelect: </label>             
    <select class="form-control" id="rotit">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/9arahevn/2/

Comment: please check question label. OP asked for bootstrap version 3.x but your solution is specific to version 4.0

Answer (score 1):

This problem is so recorrent that there is a Github project solving it

https://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/

Place their CSS file right after the CSS from Select2

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/select2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/select2-bootstrap.css">
```

Then you can use the label along with the select

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sName">Select Title</label>
    <select class="js-example-basic-single form-control" id="sName">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Neat plugin, I'm genuinely intrigued and will check it out.  However, it's overkill in terms of the original question...including a plugin vs. adding a single CSS rule.

Comment: Ugh, too late to edit...not one rule, but two - one selector to style.

Comment: Well it is just a simple css file, you could always embed it to the bootstrap :)

Comment: Even if one doesn't mind the extra files, it doesn't answer the question...or if it does, it's unclear at best. how exactly does this address the label alignment?

Comment: @ryantdecker, bootstrap does not give support for developing forms with the _select_ tag, they instead create a new type of dropdown out of the _li_ and _ul_ tags, this github project i attached add the support for the _select_ tag, with it you can build inline, horizontal or any king of form available to bootstrap up to 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

It does work if you use the latest bootstrap:
@import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');

And please DON'T FORGET to make the column with result more than 768px. Form-inline works only if screen with more than 768px. (Just drag the column with a mouse a bit)

The issue was with css for

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.form-inline .form-control {
    //old bootstrap    
    display: inline-block;

    // new bootstrap
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```